# Pundit scope in HABTM rails relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many, pundit

My current Index action looks like this:

```
  def index
    @proposals = current_user.proposals
  end
```

But I want to do it like this:

```
  def index
    @proposals = policy_scope(Proposal)
  end
```

I have a `has_and_belongs_to` relation between `User` and `Proposal`.

I'm starting to use `Pundit` gem in my application, but I don't know how to define the scope in order to have the behaviour shown above for normal users.

I want to do something like this:

```
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        user.proposals # HOW DO I DO THIS WITH THE SCOPE?
      end
    end
  end
```

How do I get the `user.proposals` using the scope variable?
I know that if I had a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relation I could do something like:

```
      else
        scope.where(user_id: user.id) # RIGHT?
      end
```

But in the case of HABTM I don't know how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `joins` to fetch proposals related to user. Something like this:

```
def resolve
  if user.admin?
    scope.all
  else
    scope.joins(:users).where(proposals_users: { user_id: user.id })
  end
end
```

Comment: It was precisely what I was looking for.